# Segmentation-Fault in C--Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, malloc

I understand that a set fault happens when you try to access memory out of the scope of your program, but I can't figure out where mine is happening, or why. I have a list defined: 
     *ListType *list = NULL;* ,
and then I add data to the List calling the add function in main:
      addNodeToList(&list, song);

```
void addNodeToList(ListType **list, SongType *song)
{
    printf("Starting Add");

    NodeType *newNode = malloc(sizeof(NodeType));
    NodeType *currNode;
    currNode = (*list)->head;
    newNode->data = song;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(currNode == NULL) {
        printf("List is Empty");
        (*list)->tail = newNode;
        (*list)->head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        (*list)->tail->next = newNode;
        (*list)->tail = newNode;
    }

}
```

The song I'm passing is properly initialized, and I can access it's elements, so I know that isn't causing the seg fault. Any help would be very appreciated!

```
typedef struct Song {
  char title[MAX_STR];
  char artist[MAX_STR];
  char album[MAX_STR];
  char duration[MAX_STR];
} SongType;

typedef struct Node {
  struct Node *next;
  SongType *data;
} NodeType;

typedef struct List {
  NodeType *head;
  NodeType *tail;
} ListType;
```

Comment: OK - run it under your debugger and step through.

Comment: Also, no data declarations/definitions shown, and indentation is less-than-optimal:(

Comment: At the very least, you should post the definitions of `ListType` and `SongType` and `NodeType` but preferably a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you insert debugging cues, you must always include a `newline` to flush the output buffer before the segfault cripples it. `printf("Starting Add\n");`

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Your debugger will tell you _where exactly_ the segfault happens.  And please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: EDIT: Added the definitions, and it shows they're indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your calling code contains:

```
ListType *list = NULL;
```

and you call your function like this:

```
addNodeToList(&list, song);
```

and in your `addNodeToList()` function you have:

```
NodeType *currNode;
currNode = (*list)->head;
```

which means you are dereferencing a null pointer `(*list)`, which crashes your code.  At minimum, check whether `*list == NULL` before setting `currNode`, but you'll need rethink the code to handle the case where `list` is a null pointer.

This code compiles, and runs.  It avoids the problem by allocating the list when necessary:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAX_STR = 64 };

typedef struct Song
{
    char title[MAX_STR];
    char artist[MAX_STR];
    char album[MAX_STR];
    char duration[MAX_STR];
} SongType;

typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node *next;
    SongType *data;
} NodeType;

typedef struct List
{
    NodeType *head;
    NodeType *tail;
} ListType;

void addNodeToList(ListType **list, SongType *song);

void addNodeToList(ListType **list, SongType *song)
{
    printf("Starting Add\n");
    assert(list != NULL);

    if (*list == NULL)
    {
        *list = malloc(sizeof(**list));
        assert(*list != 0);  // Too lazy for production
        (*list)->head = 0;
        (*list)->tail = 0;
        printf("List created\n");
    }
    NodeType *newNode = malloc(sizeof(NodeType));
    newNode->data = song;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    printf("Node created\n");

    NodeType *currNode = (*list)->head;
    if (currNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is Empty\n");
        (*list)->tail = newNode;
        (*list)->head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        (*list)->tail->next = newNode;
        (*list)->tail = newNode;
    }
    printf("Node added - all done\n");
}


int main(void)
{
    ListType *list = NULL;
    SongType  data = { "Title", "Artist", "Album", "2m 30s" };
    SongType *song = &data;

    printf("Add song once\n");
    addNodeToList(&list, song);
    printf("Add song again\n");
    addNodeToList(&list, song);
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
Add song once
Starting Add
List created
Node created
List is Empty
Node added - all done
Add song again
Starting Add
Node created
Node added - all done
```

The code leaks like a sieve; no memory is freed.

Answer (score 3):

in `main` if you're declaring

```
 ListType* list = NULL;
```

then in your function you're calling

```
 (*list)->head
```

dereferencing `(*list)` is fine, but as soon as you do `->head` it's trying to dereference that original `NULL` assignment.  You need to allocate some space for `list` first.

Comment: He hasnt posted his main function. How do you know he is not allocating space for it?

Comment: Dereferencing `list` was not fine, because it was passed as `NULL`.

Comment: My main function has some other, completely unrelated, stuff in it, but for the list that's all it has. I tried changing it to allocate memory using      ListType *list = malloc(sizeof(ListType));     but that still doesn't seem to help the seg fault.

Comment: @UnderDog I don't, but he specifically mentioned that he's got `ListType* list = NULL` in `main` and then calls `addNodeToList` with it, so I answered based on what's in the post

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is not meant to be snarky.. you sure? He has `ListType* list = NULL` and passes the address of that to his function. He should be able to do `(*list)` in his function no problem. But `(*list)` is a `NULL` value so `->head` is going to seg fault. If I'm wrong I need to pull out my junk code and get this straightened out.

Comment: @yano: I think I misspoke.  I'll delete.  I should be concentrating on work, not SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler haha that makes 2 of us... Damn SO gets addicting.

Comment: @WTL Nothing else is jumping out at me based on your edits. Could be a totally different seg fault. I think I need to see some more code at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem deals with this statement

```
ListType *list = NULL;
```

You may not call `addNodeToList` for a list initialized such a way. Otherwise there will be undefined behaviour.

You should declare the list the following way

```
ListType list = { NULL, NULL };
```

Also the function `addNodeToList` can be declared simpler

```
void addNodeToList(ListType *list, SongType *song);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can call it like

```
addNodeToList( &list, song );
```

For example

```
void addNodeToList( ListType *list, SongType *song )
{
    printf("Starting Add");

    NodeType *newNode = malloc( sizeof( NodeType ) );

    if ( newNode != NULL )
    {
        newNode->data = song;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if ( list->tail == NULL )
        {
            printf( "List is Empty\n" );
            list->head = list->tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail->next = newNode;
            list->tail = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to have a pointer to list then you should write

```
ListType *list = malloc( sizeof( ListType ) );
list->head = list-tail = NULL;;
```

and then call the function the definition of which I showed the following way

```
addNodeToList( list, song );
```

Comment: That's an overstatement at best ("You may not call `addNodeToList` for such a list").  You can call it, and it is legitimate to do so, but the called function has to handle things differently from the way it does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think it is a valid statement that you may not call a function if the call results in undefined behaviour.:)